# Find constant k with the probability mass function of a geometric series

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Ok so I'm having some trouble getting this done. I think I've got the answer but I'm not really sure on how I could verify that the result I got is actually the correct answer.

So here's what the exercise says:

$f(x) = k(\frac{1}{5})^{2x+3}$

where a discrete random variable $X = 0,1,2,3,....$

So I know this is a function for a geometric series given that the range for X is infinite.

Here's what I did:

1. $\sum\limits_{i = 0}^\infty k(\frac{1}{5})^{2x + 3} = 1$
2. $\frac{k}{125}\sum\limits_{i = 0}^\infty (\frac{1}{5})^{2x} = 1$
3. $\frac{k}{125}(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{5}}) = 1$
4. $\frac{k}{125}(\frac{5}{4}) = 1$
5. $\frac{k}{100} = 1$
6. $k = 100$

So how do I know that is ok, I thought about using limits but I'm not sure if that is correct.

Comment: $\sum\limits_{i = 0}^\infty (\frac{1}{5})^{2x} = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^\infty (\frac{1}{25})^{x} = \frac{25}{24}$

Answer (score 1):

Observe
\begin{align}
\sum_{X=0}^{\infty}k\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^{2X+3}&=\frac{k}{125}\sum_{X=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^{2X}\\
&=\frac{k}{125}\sum_{X=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{25}\right)^X\\
&=\frac{k}{125}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{25}}
\end{align}

Comment: Crap, I forgot about that small detail.